# UEFI boot possible on my mini PC?

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

Is it possible to boot from USB stick and install Ubuntu on my minin PC?
I have only the following boot options:

[image: boot options]

Would it be a solution to replace origional `.efi` in `EFI\microsotft\boot` dir in order to force USB boot?

Comment: I think the screen shot you have taken is boot option. Go to Bios option and check the boot priority. What is your mother board model?

Comment: Some mini-PCs have 32-bit EFIs, and Ubuntu doesn't support EFI-mode booting on 32-bit systems. There are workarounds, but I don't have links to any tutorials, offhand. If the system has a 64-bit EFI, be sure to use the 64-bit Ubuntu and be sure to create the USB drive with a tool and options that make it bootable in EFI mode. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html#creating-media) for more on this subject.